# Open new window when clicking Log a Call on the Activity History related list

Tags: visualforce, community, activities

I had created a Visualforce page with an Activity History related list but it doesn't pop to a new window, after clicking log a call.

Please let me know how can I make this happen.

My issue is something related to this link

["New" button in a Related List VF page.](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AZl5IAG)

Here is the code below

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" standardstylesheets="true" sidebar="false" showheader="true">


<apex:relatedList list="ActivityHistories"/>


</apex:page>
```

Comment: To be fair, the button on a standard page layout doesn't do this either.

Comment: Are you using custom button for log a call?

Comment: Would help if you post your relevant code.

Comment: It is the standard button for "Log a Call"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your example

first create a VF page

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" standardstylesheets="true" sidebar="false" showheader="true">


<apex:relatedList list="ActivityHistories"/>


</apex:page>
```

Now goto setup - task - create new button (Ex: - test btn)
create a list button(with any behaviour)

now open any account records edit page layout

goto Activity history related list link on icon and add the button in related list

Now open your page with same account reocrd id.

--Create a custom button on object and create a above vf page with related list

in custom button write code

```
window.open("/apex/myAccountCasepage?id={!Case.Id}","My page","width=550,height=170,0,status=0,");
```

[image]

Comment: I wasn't talking about adding a button. But is there a way for the related list to open up a new window ??

Comment: Yes create a vf page with above code and onlick of custom button open new window

Comment: let me know if you need help

Comment: How can I do it on a standard button like "log a Call"

Comment: means open a new task with type = call ?

Comment: Well, I would like to override the standard button "log a call" from the above picture.

Comment: Yeah you can create a custom button on Task object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32066/discussion-between-dominicseb-and-ratan).